# AMQP | What is 0-9-1 model?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

While reading [RabbitMQ tutotial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html) for basic AMQP concepts, the documentaion says "AMQP 0-9-1 is a programmable protocol".

What does 0-9-1 exactly means?

Comment: I believe is the version of AMQP. i.e version 0.9.1.  Full specs here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/specs/amqp0-9-1.pdf

Comment: AMQP has since released a 1.0 version of the protocol.  So, this is just referencing a previous version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the protocol version used (which is 1.0 actually)
for reference :

```
http://www.amqp.org/specification/0-9-1/amqp-org-download
```